# Sinatra Page Not Loading Properly

Tags: ruby, web, sinatra

I am trying to learn Sinatra. I wrote a script to scrape the job listings from Craigslist and list them on my page (just as an exercise).

The output in my terminal is exactly what I want. On my page, however, none of the information is formatted properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'httparty'
require "nokogiri"

get '/' do
  section = params['job']
  url = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/#{section}"
  response = HTTParty.get url

  html_string = response.body
  dom = Nokogiri::HTML(html_string)

  links = dom.css("a.hdrlnk")
  job_titles = links.map(&:to_str)

  job_titles.each_with_index {|job, number| puts "Job #{number}: #{job}"}
 end
```

In my terminal, I run the file and this is my output:

```
Job 0: Senior Python Software Developer
Job 1: BILLING/COLLECTIONS/FRONT DESK
Job 2: Front and Back End Web Developer
Job 3: Software Engineer
Job 4: Software Developer
Job 5: In house tech needed for website , networking, drone operation etc
```

At localhost:4567/?job=sof, I see:

Senior Python Software DeveloperBILLING/COLLECTIONS/FRONT DESKFront and Back End Web DeveloperSoftware EngineerSoftware DeveloperIn house tech needed for website , networking, drone operation etc

Comment: That's the way plain text is formatted by a browser, Perhaps you want to use HTML via a template engine like erb or haml? See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html for your options.

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would be to wrap your output with "<pre>", "</pre>"